# Deploying jenkins jobs for dynamically created gitlab repos

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Setup:
1 Jenkins server and 1 gitlab server that I own

Expected usage:
- We provision repositories for users on gitlab using some scripts when a user signs up with our portal. 
- As soon as these users submit some code in the repository, we have to run some junit tests on them and email the users with a  the test results in a clean way where they can see the passed and failed results with appropriate links which they can click on to get details of the tests.

Requirements for. jenkins:
1. Ability to send html junit test results with clickable test result links
2. Based on whether the junit test fails or passes, call two different python scripts.

Questions:
1. What is the best way to go about 1 and 2 requirements 
2. Should I create a job template and create a job per dynamically created repo or can I use same job to run tests on multiple repos

References :
These were the links we referred.But as a newbie to jenkins couldn't come up with clear solutions. 
1.https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-Jellycontent
2.https://gist.github.com/nightspotlight/7cfa6af7c7989857f336f742cdcb443b 
3.https://learn2automate.blog/2017/05/19/how-to-set-jenkins-job-status-based-on-test-case-pass/

Comment: Would users click in the links of email and this event will execute a python script or email will show a link and this link open some page in jenkins?

Comment: @JRichardsz..I want the email to show a link and this link opens some page in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Send some links in your mail using jenkins is simple

- Install https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin
- Install https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+With+Parameters+Plugin in order to expose a job as link with params
- Create some job in jenkins and in the post-build section add **editable email notification**

  ```
  [![enter image description here][1]][1]
  ```
- in In **Default Content** of **editable email notification** you must write the email body that will be sent to your users. If your requirement is send a link to allow user to open another jenkins page, you could write the following :

  ```
      In order to execute python scripts click in this link

      http://your-jenkins.com/job/my-job-python/parambuild/?param1=test1&param2=etc
  ```
- Your mail provider will render this text as html.

Finally you need to create some job with name **my-job-python** with parameters param1, param2 or whatever. This job will execute your python scripts when user clicks on email links sent by jenkins.

Comment: @JRichardsz..Thanks for the answer about email.I have a scenario that,Everytime a repository is created in gitlab i want automatically a job to be created in jenkins and when repository is deleted ,job should also be deleted....and these jobs should perform same as a job which i already have!!!

Comment: Do you have configured your webhooks in gitlab and/or jenkins? Your resume about links, scripts python or mail could be create confuse :s when your requirement is only catch events of gitlab in your jenkins.

Comment: Here a guide to configure webhook in git providers and jenkins in order to "catch events of gitlab"   https://jrichardsz.github.io/devops/devops-with-git-and-jenkins-using-webhooks

Comment: If your requirement is send email using jenkins, delete the junit, python or gitlab references on question body. If your requirement is "only catch events of gitlab in your jenkins", delete junit, mail, python on question body. This could be create confuse.